# Random Forest with seasonality

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, random-forest

I watched everywhere on the Internet, but I cannot figure out how to use random forest with a seasonality matrix.

I would start with a toy example:

```
getSymbols("GOOG")

seasonality <- matrix(0, nr=5,nc=5)
diag(seasonality) = 1
```

where 1s are Monday, Tuesday,etc.

How do I integrate this in:

```
fit <- RF(lag(GOOG.Close,1), GOOG.Close, data=GOOG[1:(NROW(GOOG)-20)])

prediction <- predict(fit,GOOG[(NROW(GOOG)-19):NROW(GOOG)])
```

Also, am I going to have problems when one business day is a holiday ?

Comment: Why not just include the days of the week and holidays as predictors?